# method destroySlider doesnt work in IE

Tags: jquery, html, bxslider

I'm trying to use this two methods in order to show elements in my page into a slider, or not.

`slider.destroySlider();`

`slider.reloadSlider();`

It's works fine in chrome and firefox, even safari, but no in IE. I also tried the methods

`slider.destroyShow()` and `slider.reloadShow()` (the old version of bxlider) whitout success.

Here is the code, it's really simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //here i create the slider...
 slider=$('#slider-2').bxSlider({
        pager: true,
        controls: true,
        moveSlideQty: 1,
        displaySlideQty: 1,
                    infiniteLoop: false,

 });
 //here, if the slider has just 1 slide, i hide the controls
 if(slider.getSlideCount()==1)
 { $("#show-all").hide();  
   $("#show-pag").hide();  
   $("#prev").hide();  
   $("#next").hide();
 }

 //here i destroy the slider when click on Show all
 $( "#show-all" ).click(function() {
     slider.destroySlider(); 
     $("#show-all").hide();
     $("#show-pag").show();
 });

 //finally, this brings the slider back 
 $( "#show-pag" ).click(function() {

      slider.reloadSlider();
      $("#show-all").show();
      $("#show-pag").hide();
 });

}
```

And here is the error code that appears in IE:

```
Webpage error details
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 76    // line where i call slider.destroySlider();
Char: 16
Code: 0
```

So.. some help? or maybe another library?

Comment: Please add a working sample/jsfiddle or provide complete code that you have tried

Comment: What is the IE version you are trying it on?